# Auto configure Vue app for multiple Firebase projects via /__/firebase/init.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

Firebase Hosting has a nice feature for auto initialising your hosted web app by inserting

```
<body>
  <!-- Previously loaded Firebase SDKs -->

  <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
</body>
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup . This allows me to deploy test/dev/staging/production Firebase project instances without updating the Firebase config.

What I’d like to do is add this as Webpack import with node_modules imports for Firebase SDKs. I’m actually using Quasar Framework which can be [configured to use Webpack rules](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-pre-processors-and-webpack.html).

I’ve had a few attempts using import ‘/__/firebase/init.js’ but Webpack is still complaining that it can’t find this dependency so I think it needs it as an external dependency.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I'm having the exact same problem...

Comment: Yes.  I just put this in the `index.template.html` file used by Quasar/Webpack to generate the `index.html` file. That way it gets ignored by Webpack.

Comment: I can now safely deploy to multiple Firebase projects and they all work fine.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot!